# Using a web service (WSDL) in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, wsdl

I have designed a web based calculator. But I want to have this calculator run on a web service(WSDL). I'm using C# and Javascript behind the back of my website. So could you help me where to add the WSDL descriptions in code and where? If required I can put my code here.   Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a request to the webservice, you don't need to put WSDL into javascript.

Calling a webservice is a request like any other request, you can use AJAX with JQuery for example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Example from: http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I'm quite new to this web service operations. So will my code look like this after I add the request?  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
}); //rest of the javascript code goes here...

Comment: If you want to use web service with javascript (in this case jquery). Check the link I put there. If you want to use the webservice from the code of you website, you should add a web reference to that. This will create the proxy to the WS automatically.

Comment: Well I used "Add Service Reference" by right-clicking the solution on Visual Studio 2010 and I successfully added the web service address to the project. Now my website still runs perfectly so could I say that my application uses the web service and does the calculation on it?

Comment: Your application has the proxy to connect to the webservice. You still need to call method from webservices to use the webservice. I mean, you need to create the code in the webservice to do the maths and then, call it from client-side or server-side (wtv you prefer).

Comment: Well I have defined methods in the web service (etc. Add, Multiply...) but I have FUNCTIONS in my javascript code so would that still make it work on the web service or what I should do? Sorry I'm asking too much but I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Do you make any call to webservice? You can call an webservice's method from Server side (like C#) or Client-Side (Ajax). You need to do a request to the webservice and read its response. I'll recommend you to search in google for "My First webservice C#" or something like this: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/tutorials/article.php/c5477

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm checking the article you've given.